# MongoDB add one documents' data into array compare with one field value on another document

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

this is the example of 'Routes' document

```
[{
routes: [{
  driver_id: "61e9536f142f337c96883c52",
  route_id:"SRT006",
  payment:13.2
}, {
  driver_id: "61e9536f142f337c96800a56",
  route_id:"SRT005",
  payment:15
}, {
  route_id:"SRT004",
  payment:20
}],
apartment: 'abc apartment',
deliverydate: "06/03/2022"
}]
```

this is the example of 'Users' document

```
[
{
  _id: ObjectId(61e9536f142f337c96883c52),
  name: 'John',
  phone: (222) 123-4568
},
{
  _id: ObjectId(61e9536f142f337c96800a56),
  name: 'Bob',
  phone: (200) 123-4568
}
]
```

Final results should be like this

```
[{
routes: [{
  driver_id: "61e9536f142f337c96883c52",
  driver_name: 'John',
  route_id:"SRT006",
  payment:13.2
}, {
  driver_id: "61e9536f142f337c96800a56",
  driver_name: 'Bob',
  route_id:"SRT005",
  payment:15
}, {
  route_id:"SRT004",
  payment:20
}],
apartment: 'abc apartment',
deliverydate: "06/03/2022"
}]
```

I have tried $lookup to add driver_name but getting errors. Any advice on what is the approach to getting the above results on MongoDB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `$lookup` - `routes` collection join with `users` collection via pipeline.

   1.1. `$in` - Filter the document with `_id` (converted to `string` type) is in `routes_driver_id` array.

   1.2. `$project` - Decorate output document(s) to be returned in the `driver` array.
2. `$set` - Set `routes` field.

   2.1. `$map` - Iterate each element in the `routes` array and returns a new array.

   2.1.1. `$mergeObjects` - Merge current iterated document with the result *2.1.1.1*.

   2.1.1.1. `$first` - Get the first value of the array from *2.1.1.1.1*.

   2.1.1.1.1. `$filter` - Filter the `driver` document by matching current `route`'s `_id` with `driver_id` (converted to `string` type).
3. `$unset` - Remove `driver` field.

```
db.routes.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "users",
      "as": "driver",
      "let": {
        routes_driver_id: "$routes.driver_id"
      },
      "pipeline": [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $in: [
                {
                  $toString: "$_id"
                },
                "$$routes_driver_id"
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $project: {
            _id: 0,
            driver_id: "$_id",
            name: 1
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      routes: {
        $map: {
          input: "$routes",
          as: "route",
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              "$$route",
              {
                $first: {
                  $filter: {
                    input: "$driver",
                    cond: {
                      $eq: [
                        "$$route.driver_id",
                        {
                          $toString: "$$this.driver_id"
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unset: "driver"
  }
])
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/zYrgfiFelmQ)

Comment: Thank you for the quick and well-explained answer. It is working perfectly. `$toObjectId` is not working whenever $$route.driver_id is coming empty string. I have corrected that line as given below: 
`{ $convert: { input: '$$route.driver_id', to: 'objectId', onError: '', onNull: '' } },`

Comment: I see, if `$$route.driver_id` may have empty string, you may remove the `$toObjectId`, but cast `$$this.driver_id` to `string` type. But your approach with `$toObjectId` for error handling is correct too.